# How to remove xml tag and put it inside another tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file as below.

```
<note>
<from> </from>
<to>
    <name> </name>
    <number> </number>
</to>
<message>
    <head> </head>
    <body> </body>
</message>
</note>
```

I want to build xml structure like below using XSTL.

```
<note>
<from> </from>

<message>
    <name> </name>
    <number> </number>
    <head> </head>
    <body> </body>
</message>
</note>
```

I have tried something like this.

```
<xsl:template match="//to">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//message"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off with the Identity Template, which on its own copies nodes to the output document "as-is"

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you then only have to write templates for nodes you wish to actually change.

For a start, you don't want **to** appearing in the same place in the output, so add a template to ignore it

```
<xsl:template match="to" />
```

Next, you want to transform the **message** element to append the child of the **to** elements to it. You do this with the following template, which is similar to the Identity Template, but with an extra line to do the extra copying.

```
<xsl:template match="message">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="../to/*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="to" />

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../to/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```